# Как скрыть форму при ее отправке PHP?

Tags: php, html, form, phpmailer

Есть форма через PHPMailer, хотелось бы, чтобы при отправке форма скрывалась и на ее месте появлялась благодарность (без перенаправления на другую страницу, потому что почему-то, когда я перенаправляю на страницу с благодарностью, письмо на почту не приходит, при этом если перенаправлять на несуществующую страницу - все отлично...)

код:

```
<?php 



require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';


$theme = $_POST['theme'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$comment = $_POST['comment'];



$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;       

$mail->Username = 'mail@mail.ru'; 

$mail->Password = 'pass';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->Port = 465;



$mail->setFrom('mail@mail.ru');

$mail->addAddress('omail@mail.ru');



$mail->isHTML(true);



$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с сайта';

$mail->Body = "Тема: $theme<br>Почта: $email<br>Комментарий: $comment";

$mail->AltBody = '';



if(!$mail->send()) {

    echo 'Error';

} else {

    header('location: thank-you.html');

}

?>
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не решить исходную проблему с перенаправлением? Скорее всего вы неверно интерпретируете результат. Почта отправляется в момент `$mail->send()`, а то куда вы потом редиректите никак на отправку не влияет.

Answer (score -1):

Это достигается средствами ajax. Нужно поставить прослушку на клик по кнопке отрпавить и по клику запускать ajax функцию.

Из html формы можно убрать путь до скрипта, method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
      sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form', 'action_ajax_form.php'); //Запускаем ajax функцию
      return false;
    }
  );
});

function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url, //url страницы скрипта (action_ajax_form.php)
    type: "POST", //метод отправки
    dataType: "html", //формат данных
    data: $("#" + ajax_form).serialize(), // Сеарилизуем объект
    success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
      result = $.parseJSON(response);
      $('#result_form').html('благодраность'); //#result_form - блок куда выврдим благодароность
    },
    error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
      $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
    }
  });
```

Comment: jQuery -- это, конечно, клёво, но в 2022 такое решение кажется архаичным.  Современный js не менее выразителен и не требует подключения сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Тут 4 строчки на JQuery вообще ничего не поменяется если написать `$` или `getElementById`. И вопрос в целом не о споре

Comment: Ну это мы с вами такие умные и понимаем, что можно писать getElementById (querySelector) и fetch. А некоторые из тех, кто найдут этот ответ в поиске, просто скопируют ваше решение и добавят в свои проекты. Подумайте о новичках.